# Is there a way to avoid the trade-off between readability and performance when looping?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So this is a readable way (the code doesn't matter, what matters is the style):

```
arr.map().filter() // looping 2 times
```

And loops are considered as a faster way:

```
for(/* whatever */) { 
  // looping once, and doing all we need in the same loop
}
```

So my question is: is there a way, maybe from the functional programming world, to combine the readability of the former with the performance of the latter?

P.S. There is a trend to downvote such questions. If you want to, please write the reason as well.

Comment: I am not entirely convinced that `filter().map()` (in that order) is slower than a for loop if you ignore the function call overheads. Yes it loops two times but `for (...) { do two things }` is the same as `for (...) { do one thing } for (...) { do another thing }` since you end up doing the same number of things.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the opinion! So you mean there is ultimately the same number of operations? Interesting point. You mean the loop itself is almost nothing in terms of performance? Is it so?

Comment: In most cases the performance loss by using methods over `for` is negligible. Despite this question leaning towards being primarily opinionated (_readable_ code is subjective - I find for-loops just fine), there are definitely ways to do what you are asking, for one the [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) library.

Comment: Short version. What a loop does that is "expensive" is increment a variable and check a condition. If your loop body is significantly more expensive than that then you can just ignore it as really minuscule.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you! I needed this.

Comment: @chazsolo Thanks! You solidified the point of apokryfos, which I agreed with. Also, thanks for lazy.js, I am not concerned about performance to that extent, but it probably will be useful in future!

Comment: I think this is a great example of [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). Do your benchmarks show that the functional style is measurably different from the explicit loop?

Comment: If you are working with large dataset, you might actually get performance gains using the functional style and lazy evaluation (lazy.js mentioned, [wu](https://fitzgen.github.io/wu.js/) is another. Generally the performance is greatly affected by the big picture and a little by small details.

Comment: @wbadart Nope, no benchmarks have been conducted. And this was probably my problem. The thought just sparked in my head and here we are.

Comment: @SamiHult Agree. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is.

1st alternative: Transducer

```js
const mapReduce = map => reduce => (acc, x) =>
  reduce(acc, map(x));

const filterReduce = filter => reduce => (acc, x) =>
  filter(x)
    ? reduce(acc, x)
    : acc;

const transduce = (...ts) => xs =>
  xs.reduce(ts.reduce(comp, id) (concat), []);
  
const comp = (f, g) =>
  x => f(g(x));
  
const id = x => x;

const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs.concat(ys);
  
const sqr = n => n * n;
const isOdd = n => n & 1 === 1;
const log = console.log;

// the upper code is usually library code
// so you don't have to deal with its complexity but only with its API

const tx = filterReduce(isOdd),
  ty = mapReduce(sqr);
  
const r = transduce(tx, ty) ([1,2,3,4,5]); // filter/map in same iteration

log(r);
```

2nd alternative: Bare recursion with a tail call optimization effect

```js
const loop = f => {
   let acc = f();

   while (acc && acc.type === tailRec)
     acc = f(...acc.args);

   return acc;
};

const tailRec = (...args) =>
   ({type: tailRec, args});
   
const comp = (f, g) => x =>
  f(g(x));
  
const sqr = n => n * n;
const isOdd = n => n & 1 === 1;
const log = console.log;

// the upper code is usually library code
// so you don't have to deal with its complexity but only with its API

const r = loop((xs = [1,2,3,4,5], acc = [], i = 0) => {
  if (i === xs.length)
    return acc;
    
  else 
    return tailRec( // filter/map in same iteration
      xs,
      isOdd(xs[i]) ? acc.concat(sqr(xs[i])) : acc,
      i + 1);
});
    
log(r);
```

I'd say transducer are for normal, simpler iterations whereas recursion is suitable for more complex ones, for example when you need short circuiting (prematurely exiting).

Comment: I got it, so there are three alternatives in the trade-off: performance, readability and mental resource :) Nothing is free, as always. Thanks! I need a weekend to digest this completely, though.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think having some for-loops in your code makes it unreadable, but that's opinion based I suppose.

There are many ways to make your code more readable. If you're going to use this functionality often then you could create a method to add to `Array.prototype` - this way you can write the for-loop once and call it when you need it without having to see what you consider ugly code. Below is an example:

```js
//This method will now be available to all Arrays instances:
Array.prototype.prettyLoop = function() {
  console.log('All I do is execute a basic for-loop');
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    console.log(this[i]);
  }
};

//Call the method from your script
["a", 1, null, "x", 1989, false, {}].prettyLoop();
```

Comment: Honestly this is far from what I really meant, but thanks for the contribution +1

Comment: I don't think the for loop is much less readable. I *do* think it's less testable. I also think it's more error-prone (off-by-one, closure in the loop, bad initialization, etc.). Readability is a little more subjective: but there's plenty not to like about for loops.